# sshd, httpd and crond processes use high CPU in Ubuntu 14.04 Server

Tags: 14.04, cron, cpu, sshd

I have a production server with Ubuntu 14.04 OS. I am observing some suspicious behavior from sshd, HTTPd and crond.

Suddenly these processes have started to use 100% of CPU. If I kill these processes CPU utilization becomes normal.

```
nice top -c
```

[image: top command output here]

```
lsof -n -p 8310
```

[image: lsof command output here]

```
cat /proc/8310/maps
```

Please find the cat command output link in the command section

I am running a java process in this server and in normal condition there will be almost 98% idle CPU. CPU usage will be high until I kill these process.

How can I solve it?

Comment: https://s3.amazonaws.com/superuser12/catcmd1.png and https://s3.amazonaws.com/superuser12/catcmd2.png

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting/

Comment: None of what you have posted shows any problems as far as I can see.

Comment: @SorenA is there any way that I can find which process/cmd triggered this httpd process. I am using apache-tomcat to serve the website. What will be the reason suddenly httpd, sshd process using 50-80 % CPU

Comment: @hari you can continue using `top` to show which processes that are using cpu and other resources. And if httpd is the one using all cpu, you will have to analyze what requests are triggering this.